# phonegap android: set volumeupbutton and volumedownbutton event but e.preventDefault() not working

Tags: android, cordova

I have add the code in my .java file:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    //If volume down key
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN) {
        this.loadUrl("javascript:cordova.fireDocumentEvent('volumedownbutton');");
        //return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) {
        this.loadUrl("javascript:cordova.fireDocumentEvent('volumeupbutton');");
        //return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    } else {
        //return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event); 
    }
    //return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

I want to stop the volume change event than to do something when I press the volume key:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                document.addEventListener("volumeupbutton", onVolumeUpKeyDown, false);  
                document.addEventListener("volumedownbutton", volumedownbutton, false);
        });
            function onVolumeUpKeyDown(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                alert("key up pressed");

            }

            function volumedownbutton(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                alert("key down pressed");
            }
```

But when I pressed the volume button, the volume still changing even the alert message shown...
Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's mentioned in the documentation that it's supported for Blackberry 10 only

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#volumeupbutton

> Supported Platforms
>
> BlackBerry 10

I don't see any other platforms in the listing for this event.